# Oracle 10g - Lock table where two procedures might update this same table synchronously

Tags: sql, synchronization, oracle10g

I want to lock a table in Oracle 10g, so that e.g. procedure A has to wait till procedure B is finished with updating. I read a about the Command LOCK TABLE, but I am not sure, if the other procedure is waiting for the lock to be aquired. 
What's also possible is that another thread is calling the same stored procedure B during the update-process, I guess that since stored procedure is running in a single thread, this would be also a problem?

Comment: You wouldn't normally want to lock a *whole table* in Oracle, though of course locking in general is an important issue.  Without knowing your specific requirements it is hard to advise.  By default if 2 sessions try to update the same row then the second will be "blocked" and will have to wait for the first to commit or rollback its change.  You can use a select with `for update` clause to lock a row without updating it.

Comment: The table is used for reports generated on the fly. So it changes evertime the procedures are triggered. I guess views might be better for that use-case but it's not my call to make.

Comment: Maybe use a Global Temporary Table?  Then each session has its own copy.

Comment: Thanks, I would accept his as an answer, but i think you can't do this with comments .

Comment: I'll make it into an answer then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't normally want to lock a **whole table** in Oracle, though of course locking in general is an important issue. By default if 2 sessions try to update the same row then the second will be "blocked" and will have to wait for the first to commit or rollback its change. You can use a select with for update clause to lock a row without updating it.

Instead of using a single regular table shared by all sessions, you could use a [Global Temporary Table](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7002.htm#i2153132): then each session has its own copy.